# axis parallel rectangles

Tags: discrete-geometry

Assume $\mathcal{F}$ such a family of axises-parallel rectangles, any two of them intersects by a horizontal or vertical line. Prove there exist a pair of line $(v, h)$ vertical and horizontal such that any $R\in\mathcal{F}$ intersects any of $(v,h)$.

Comment: What is your work on the subject?

Comment: First I thought that the following arguments works, but I find a counterexample...

Comment: Let $I=[a_1,b_1]\times [c_1,d_1], J=[a_2, b_2]\times[c_2, d_2]\in\mathcal{F}$ be the ones with the most left right-edge and the most down up-edge respectively. Let $X=b_1$ and $Y= d_2$. I tohought  the pair $(X, Y)$ has the desired property...